# Find $T$ and $U$ of $R^{2}\rightarrow R^{2}$ such that $TU=0$ but $UT\neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have serious problem with this exercise

> Find $T$ and $U$ of $R^{2}\rightarrow R^{2}$ such that $TU=0$ but
>   $UT\neq0$

I try different ways, with the associated matrix of $T$, with an invertible linear transformation, but i cannot solve this. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: I would note that neither of these matrices can be invertible for this to work. (you can reason this by considering ranks)

Comment: I want to ask if all solutions to this are of the form $T = \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{bmatrix},$ $U = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.$ What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I would think about it as a picture. If $U$ puts everything onto  the $y$-axis, and $T$ kills the $y$-axis, then $TU = 0$. This still leaves you with some freedom as to what $T$ does to the $x$-axis. Can you figure out how to arrange it so that $UT = 0$ as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try looking at $2 \times 2$ matrices with three $0$s and one $1$.  You might stumble onto the example
$$
T = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad U = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$

Comment: You say, my answer could be $T(x,y)=(x,0)$ and
$U(x,y)=(0,y)$ ?

Comment: No, I would say that $U(x,y) = (y,0)$.  Or, I would just say that $U$ is the matrix $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, which is what I did say.