# Find an example of a 2D linear transformation $T$ such that $T^{2}\equiv 0$ but $T\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i was thinking about this exercise.

> Find an example of a linear transformation of $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to
> > R^{2}$ such that $T^{2}\equiv0$ but $T\neq0$

What conditions must the transformation have for that to happen?

I find some examples, of that:

$T(x,y)=(x-y,y-x)$.
That example work perfectly.

In this particular example, it occurs that: $rank(T)=nul(T)=1$

But, is a little difficult find other examples of this, can someone help me?

Comment: Even more than $rank(T)=nul(T)=1$ you can then go further and prove that $Im(T)=\ker(T)$.  Take any basis of the domain, $\{v,u\}$ and define $T(v)=u$ and $T(u)=0$.  This uniquely defines the transformation and it clearly satisfies the properties you desire.

Comment: $T^2=0$ is equivalent to say that the representing matrix $[T]$ of the linear transformation $T$ is idempotent. This can happen only when all eigenvalues of $[T]$ are $0$. Also $T\neq 0$ tells that $[T]$ is not diagonalizable, and its Jordan canonical form must be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: @FrankLu Instead of idempotent should be nilpotent.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259811/find-t-and-u-of-r2-rightarrow-r2-such-that-tu-0-but-ut-neq0/2259812#2259812) is related.